# Changing layout group childForceExpand with code

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am just wondering how to access the `childForceExpand` of the layout groups with code. I'm attaching Vertical layout groups to instantiated panels and want to turn the force expand off.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like so:

```
  using UnityEngine.UI;

  VerticalLayoutGroup grp = GetComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>();
  grp.childForceExpandHeight = true;
  grp.childForceExpandWidth = false;
```

Comment: could have sworn i tried that last night and got an error on it, must have miss spelled it and not noticed, thank you